# BootStrap css is not working having showHeader=“True” on visual force page

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap, header-bar

Create a VF page using the BootStrap CSS library and everything works just fine if the **showHeader is equals FALSE**. But If I try to include bootstrap in a vf page with `showHeader="True"` salesforce styles will get messed up. I am not using apex tags , I am using only html Tags.

Any ideas? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: you need to use namespace bootstrap.. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202817/is-there-any-ready-to-use-bootstrap-css-file-with-prefix and try to implement same

Answer (score 2):

You can try one thing. Add Namespace in your `bootstrap.css` file and then use it. It will solve your file.

Use this [link](http://www.css-prefix.com/) to add namespace and then in your vf page code make one outer element

```
<div class="yourclass" >
 //all code inside.
</div>
```

**Note** There is one drawback of this method is sometime model does not work correctly. but if you don't need them then its good choice for you.

Comment: I added the prefix but now whole bootstrap is not working any changes on page are required ?

Comment: check your bootstrap remove namespace from start element . also check if you put div correctly.

Comment: can You please tell me what should be add in .yourclass ?